# Automatically Change Open to Short

Tags: switches, transformer, short-circuit

We have a field device that is connected to the secondary winding of a transformer. The device  is replaceable, but when it is disconnected, the open circuit can cause problems elsewhere on our circuit.

Here's a rough diagram of our device, connected to the transformer (**Connected**):
[image]

We need to be able to disconnect the device from the transformer, but leave a short circuit instead of an open (**Disconnected**):
[image]

We're hoping for a solution that doesn't involve microchips or other digital technology, but that's a preference that we can work around if we can't have it.
Ideally, we'd like a packaged solution, but it's been difficult enough for us just to find something that fits our description, so even a schematic or basic theorycrafting would be helpful.

Comment: Relay. Mechanical switch. Two FETs in series. Switch, As a short is acceptable you can throw a switch to short the winding then remove the load. Presumably it's not a power transfiormer of the usual type. Telling us what you are actually doing would help.

Comment: Do you really need a short or could a resistor be sufficient?  What is the problem caused by the open circuit? How much voltage and current?

Comment: Problem: It can cause an explosion, when there is an open circuit in the secondary side of a current transformer.

Comment: The neutral current transformer is 40 Amps Primary: 5 Amps Secondary.

Comment: A parallel resistor to the current transformer would work. However, we are looking for an automatic solution, a solution that will automatically detect the open circuit and automatically go back to its regular state once the cable is plug into the device again.

Answer (score 4):

Before there were microprocessors, there was...hardware.
[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Jack-plug--socket-switch.jpg]

For low-voltage, audio, etc., this is what you want.  As it closes a circuit when you pull the plug, you can even wire in an impedance-correct resistor, if that's what you really wanted.

[photo credit "Ianf", found on en.wikipedia.org]

Answer (score 1):

If a true short is wanted a simple SPST switch will do fine. (SPST = single pole single throw = on/off).

The switch can be closed to provide the short circuit before removal of the field device and opened after reinsertion of the field device.

If a short is a bit violent a dummy load can be in series with the switch.

A simple SPST switch can be mechanically interlocked so the field device cannot be removed until the switch is moved to the short position.
 Also the switch can be interlocked so it cannot be opened with the field device absent.

---

Other possibilities:

Relay.

Two FETs in series.

---

Presumably it's not a power transfiormer of the usual type.
 Telling us what you are actually doing would help.

Comment: The Device is a QEI Automatic Capacitor Controller. We want to disconnect automatically from the Capacitor Controller without causing an open circuit in the current transformer. A parallel relay or parallel resistor could work, however, it may introduce an error to our control box if we do not calculate the exact amount. We are looking for something automatically that will detect the open circuit due to the disconnection from our control box, and will go
back to regular working conditions once the cable is connected back again to the control box.

Comment: The neutral current transformer ratio is 40Amps primary : 5Amps secondary.
This problem could be solve by adding extra components, however, it will be still be a mechanical solution. Do you know of a module that could automatically detect the open circuit, create a short circuit in the secondary side of the current transformer and go back to regular working conditions, once the cable is connected back to the control
box?
Thank you for your help,